# does windows 7 bluetooth stack and API support connection of headsets

Tags: c++, windows-7, bluetooth

We need to write code to search for, pair and connect to a bluetooth headset with Windows 7 Embedded.

Once connected the headset will be used as a normal windows audio device.

We fully control what software is installed on the system so conflicting stacks and similar concerns are not a problem.  We would however like to minimize as far as possible installing extra software such as 3rd party stacks.

Therefore my question is: can the built in windows 7 bluetooth stack and C++ API alone be used to create the functionality we need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 does not contain an in-box driver for BT audio, however if you pair an audio device an audio driver should be available from windows update.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this is useful to anyone, the answer was yes the windows 7 stack does support headset out of the box using the Bluetooth api.  The background to the question was we were coming from windows xp where the headset profile was not natively supported.

Also Larry Osterman is correct about the BT audio driver.